# How to establish a custom material theme in angular storybook?

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes, angular-storybook

I am importing my custom theme.scss inside of preview.ts like this

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!./../src/theme.scss';
```

and my theme.scss looks like that:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

// colors
$primary-default: #2364a5;
$primary-light: #a7a6ff;
$primary-dark: #13338f;

$primary-palette: (
  // lighter
  300: $primary-default,
  // default
  600: $primary-light,
  // darker
  900: $primary-dark,
  contrast: (
    // light contrast color
    300: "#fff",
    // medium contrast color
    600: "#fff",
    // bold contrast color
    900: "#fff"
  )
);

$secondary-default: #f5db5f;
$secondary-light: #f2e4a2;
$secondary-dark: #a8953b;

$secondary-palette: (
  // lighter
  300: $secondary-default,
  // default
  600: $secondary-light,
  // darker
  900: $secondary-dark,
  contrast: (
    // light contrast color
    300: "#fff",
    // medium contrast color
    600: "#fff",
    // bold contrast color
    900: "#fff"
  )
);

$hv-landing-page-primary: mat.define-palette(
  theme.$primary-palette,
  600,
  300,
  900
);

$hv-landing-page-accent: mat.define-palette(
  theme.$secondary-palette,
  600,
  300,
  900
);

$hv-landing-page-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$hv-landing-page-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $hv-landing-page-primary,
    accent: $hv-landing-page-accent,
    warn: $hv-landing-page-warn,
  )
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($hv-landing-page-theme);


html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

but when I apply mat-raised-button and color="primary" to one of my buttons the theme just does not apply...(yep, I imported the MatButtonModule)

I could at least solve that the import statement is working. When I write a test class with some dark background-color it is applied... but the angular material theme just won't apply..
Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the original Storybook executors for Angular (like  `@storybook/angular:build-storybook` to build Storybook), you can apply a custom theme in the options of the executor. See the official [Storybook for Angular documentation (expand the "Troubleshooting" section)](https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/install#troubleshooting) for more details.

Add the desired style sheets to your `angular.json` or `project.json` (when using Nx):

```
"build-storybook": {
  "executor": "@storybook/angular:build-storybook",
  "options": {
    "styles": ["theme.scss"]
  }
}
```

You probably need to adjust the path of `theme.scss` depending on where the files are placed.